# AutocompleteTextView не закрывался диалог на кнопку "back"

Tags: android

Всем привет! Как сделать так чтобы диалог AutocompleteTextView не закрывался на кнопку "back". Т.е я хочу сделать так чтобы пользователь обязательно выбрал какой-нибудь вариант.

Comment: А если пользователь не хочет? ну вот не знает он, что ему делает, а Вы навязываете. Хотя я знаю - он просто закроет приложение и забудет о нем. В лучшем случае.

Comment: Здесь пожалуй вы правы. Я отказался от такой затеи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы посмотрите на метод [`AutocompleteTextView.onKeyPreIme`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java#394), то увидите, что именно в нём вызывается метод `dismissDropDown` по нажатию на кнопку back.

Стало быть, вам нужно создать наследника `AutocompleteTextView`, в котором переопределить метод `onKeyPreIme` следующим образом:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: После первого ответа, я порылся в исходниках, и нашел что нужно переопределять метод onKeyPreIme. За ответ всё равно спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Вызывать дочерний от  AutocompleteTextView диалог в котором метод обработки "back" должен быть переопределён - это азы ООП :)